# Why are vertex operators integrated over the worldsheet?

Tags: operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, path-integral

In chapter $3$ of Polchinski after discussing why vertex operators are used for preparing states in S-matrix. We are given the vertex operator for closed string tachyon is $$V_0=2g_c\int d^2\sigma\sqrt{g}e^{ik\cdot X}\tag{3.6.1}$$
I'm lost here: in the limit of a very long cylinder, for initial state preparation, the vertex operator became an operator at *a point* - so how will we do the integration of something at a point? We can introduce a delta function but it's bad because it destroys all the local worldsheet symmetries.

This question is discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540502) as well. The answer ultimately boils down to the following: $$S(k)= \sum_\mathrm{compact\\ topologies} \int \frac{[\mathrm dX\ \mathrm dg]}{V_\mathrm{diff \times Weyl}} \exp(-S_{x}-\lambda\chi)\prod_{a=1}^{n} \int d^{2}{\sigma} \sqrt{g} :e^{ik_{a}X_{a}}:\tag{3.5.5}$$
Is it an assumption or can we derive this relation?

Comment: ... of which book?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Sorry! the name of the book totally slipped my mind

Comment: @NiharKarve in ch-2 (sec $2.8$) while defining vertex operator (VO) Polchinski defines VO at exactly $z=0$. What I meant was how can we integrate something defined only at a point, for ex.  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ where $f(x)=2, x=10$ and $f(x)=0, x\neq10$?

Comment: @NiharKarve I'm probably making some mistake with VO and state operator isomorphism. I'll read into it and get back to this question.

Comment: @aitfel it is defined at a point (in the natural fixed picture) , and the you need to translate to integrated picture to define it globally and be able to integrate it. this map is sometimes very non-trivial (especially when there is curvature) so it is good you don’t consider it obvious